# How do I block exim from sending spam?

Tags: email, spam-prevention, exim, dkim

My exim 4 is sending spam from a random-name@mydomain.com address. How is this possible and how do I allow only www-data@localhost to send and to only deliver from myname@mydomain.com to myname@gmail.com (as in my aliases list)?

I'm new to mail configuration. I have a webuzo on my server but I have successfully installed dovecot and exim 4, but all mail sent from that server enters spam.

How do I install dkim, sender id to stop it from spam?

Comment: Are you sure the mails are sent from your server? It is possible to send mails with your name as sender from other servers.

Comment: Contents of /etc/exim/exim.conf would be helpful. What is `relay_from_hosts` set to?

Comment: @Sleafar It is also possible that spams are sent from the host without MTA/exim "help".

Answer (score 1):

The first step should be to determine if your server is actually originating the mail.  It is quite possible that some other server is sending the mail and spoofing your address.

If you can get the headers of one of the messages, check to see if it ever passed through your server.  This can be spoofed, in which case the recipient's boarder server will have received the mail from the real server, or an open relay.  This can be mitigated with a strict SPF policy.  Add a text record like `v=spf1 mx -all` should signal to other servers that the mail is likely spam.

If the mail is sent from your server, it could be originating from a spambot running on the server.  In this case, exim may not be handling the mail at all.  On Linux, you can use an `iptables` rule to prevent other processes from sending mail to the Internet.

If your exim server is sending the mail it should be logged in your `mainlog`.  This should log all the messages your server is sending.

If exim is sending the mail you can verify the sender for local addresses.  Normally this is bypassed at the start of the recipient ACL.

If the mail is being relayed though your server, you may need to tighten restrictions on which servers you relay for.  As a starting point, require authentication for all mail being relayed from the Internet.